# Trying to position my image a little bit lower, but it drags everything down with it

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-2, image

I'm trying to position my picture a little bit lower so the center of the image aligns with the vertical center of the header tag.

Here is the both the HTML and the CSS. Thanks for the help!

[image]

```
#articlesummary
{
    border: 2px solid red;    
    width: 750px;
}

#articlesummary h3
{
    border: 2px solid red;
    display:inline;
    color: #4292C6;    
    font-family: Verdana;
}

#articlesummary img
{   
    width:30px; 
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 5px;   
}

.submissionowner
{
    color: Gray;
}

<% foreach (var article in Model) { %>
<div id="articlesummary">
    <h3><%: article.Title %></h3>
    <sub class="submissionowner">Submmited by: <%: article.SiteUser.Login %></sub>
    <img src="../../Content/anonymous.png" alt="Anonymous user." />
    <p><%: article.Body %></p>
    <sub>Views:<%: article.TotalViews %> | Rating: <%: article.TotalRating %></sub>
</div>    
<% } %>
```

Thanks a bunch for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to vertical-align: middle your img... like this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Sorry, wrong link/property posted

Your img class will look like this:

```
#articlesummary img
{   
    width:30px; 
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 5px;   
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: What? Why would I want to align the text to the center? I want the image to be centered VERTICALLY with the h3 tag, so the image doesn't appear as high and unaligned.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use a `<br />` tag, it will lower it, but maybe too low.

Comment: If you add the backtick character (``) around the `<br/>` code it will appear correctly instead of being rendered

Comment: Don't use semantics to style.